# Where can i find the website in blazor aspnet core hosted?

Tags: blazor

I have downloaded the blazor aspnetcore hosted template, I now deployed it using Docker. Running the container works fine and i can even access api points via

http://localhost:5000/api/SampleData/Whatever

Now the question is which url do i need to enter to get to my example webpage?

Comment: It ought to be launched from the root of your app, ie `http://localhost:5000/`

Comment: No there is no website. I also tried with a vanilla project from the template but same problem: This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5000/

Comment: Can you try locally (w/o Docker) first?

Comment: that works. Looks like the error is when publishing to linux

Comment: Can you verify that the client gets deployed at all?  I'm not sure about the exact folder structure but the _framework folder and the index.html file should be somewhere in there.

Comment: surprisingly it doesnt work anymore if i change the folder of the publish. I checked both results and with the default publish (which works), i get a a different folder structure: on the same level as the publish folder are lots of dlls and the server.exe there works. If i go into the publish folder (which should be the actual publish), the server.exe doesnt work. EDIT: the api works fine in the "broken" published version

Comment: i found that the blazor.config files are completly different. Looks like the error is in there: The working version has absolute paths and the other version has relative paths (eg: . and Foldername/)